# EmitVertex gives "error C1067: too little data in type constructor"

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader, gl-triangle-strip

I am using geometry shaders to generate cubes from GL_POINTS

```
#version 150 core

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 18) out;

in vec3 g_col[];

out vec3 f_col;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    f_col = g_col[0];

    float s = gl_in[0].gl_PointSize * 0.5;

    vec4 c = gl_in[0].gl_Position;

    // Bottom

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, -s, -s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (+s, -s, -s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, +s, -s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (+s, +s, -s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    // Far

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, +s, +s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (+s, +s, +s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    // Top

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, -s, +s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (+s, -s, +s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    // Near

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, -s, -s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (+s, -s, -s, 0));
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();

    // Left

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, -s, -s));
    EmitVertex ();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, +s, -s));
    EmitVertex ();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, -s, +s));
    EmitVertex ();

    gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, +s, +s));
    EmitVertex ();

    EndPrimitive ();
}
```

If I delete the code after the first `EndPrimitive` (before the `// Left` comment), this correctly draws a strip around a cube, leaving the sides uncapped.

If I try to draw a new triangle strip to cap the side, I get this error for each of the four subsequent `EmitVertex` calls:

```
error C1067: too little data in type constructor
```

According to [this documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader)

> The GS defines what kind of primitive these vertex outputs represent. The GS can also end a primitive and **start a new one**, by calling the EndPrimitive() function. This does not emit a vertex.
>
> In order to write two independent triangles from a GS, you must write three separate vertices with EmitVertex() for the first three vertices, then **call EndPrimitive() to end the strip and start a new one**. Then you write three more vertices with EmitVertex().

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the working part:

> ```
> gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (+s, -s, -s, 0));
> ```

In the non-working part:

> ```
> gl_Position = transform * (c + vec4 (-s, -s, -s));
> ```

A `vec4` constructor needs four components, just as the error message tells you.